# Appium 1.10.0 + Android : Unable to accept permission alert

Tags: automated-testing, python, appium, mobile-automation

Team,

I am facing issues to accept the permission on Android using Appium. I have tried below options:

- capabilities.SetCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);
- driver.switch_to_alert()
- driver.findElement(By.id("Allow_buttonID")).click();
- mobile:acceptAlert [UIAutomator2 specific]

Still unable to accept the permission alerts i.e. Unable to tap on "Allow"

**My environment :**

- Windows : 10
- Appium : 1.10.0
- Platform : Android[8.1.1/9.0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution** :

- Finally solution worked for me was **using text "Allow"**

> driver.findElement(By.Name("Allow")).click();

- Did not understand why other all tried solution failed for simple alert. Happy now working